# how to use async task to check background data when there is no network call

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a json response which is loading from api in particular activity in background.This data is for another acitivity which is done to reduce time when landing activity is clicked.

when the landing activity is loaded and if it is on cellular network and at the same time if landing activity is clicked by user then that data is still not loaded i.e it is still loading.

In this state i want to have a check in landing activity that if the data for array is empty then it must show loader and if it is loaded then display data.

Basically can we use async task when there is no network call.In my case network call for data is already done in previous activity I just want to check data in array in background.

or
Is there any another solution to keep check in background.?
Can anyone help?

Comment: I think you can use static boolean. When data is loading that set this boolean to true and as soon as data is loaded then make is false.When you want to check in activity simple check this boolean value..!!

Comment: but I want to have a continous check on data in activity till then it should show a loader.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this timer for specific time to check if data is downloaded or not.

```
private void startTimer(int timerCount) {
            int count = timerCount; // milliseconds for which task eill be running
            mTimer1 = new Timer();
            mTt1 = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    mTimerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            if (!YourActivity.isDownloaded) {

                            } else {

                            }

                        }
                    });
                }
            };

            mTimer1.schedule(mTt1, 1, 1000);
        }
```

**Note** : Please stop timer when data is downloaded or activity is stopped.

Hope It will help.

Comment: I haven't use your timer code but I want to know this from you that is this the correct way of doing this stuff?
i have declared json array as `public static` in activity where data is loaded...then in landing activity i wrote a async task and in `doInBackground` i have wrote `if(DashBoardActivity.mMemberResponseParser!=null) mMemberResponseParser=DashBoardActivity.mMemberResponseParser;`
 and in `onPostExecute` I am passing that `mMemberResponseParser` to adapter.So when it is filled the adapter will be called.

Comment: @ Bunny : I am afraid that my approach is not ideal one and yours one may be do not work. How about you add callback while downloading data and call it when its done.On getting call fill adapter and when you fill adapter dismiss() dialog..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could just have a **broadcast receiver** registered in your landing activity, and then in your previous Activity where your **Async task** is running, just perform the check in your **onPostExecute** to see if the data is received correctly, and if yes then send a broadcast which will be received in your landing activity where in, you can then dismiss the loader in your landing activity.

Comment: What I have done now...i have declared json array as `public static` in activity where data is loaded...then in landing activity i wrote a async task and in `doInBackground` i have wrote `if(DashBoardActivity.mMemberResponseParser!=null)
   mMemberResponseParser=DashBoardActivity.mMemberResponseParser;`
and in `onPostExecute` I am passing that `mMemberResponseParser`to adapter.So when it is filled the adapter will be called.
Is it correct way of doing?

Comment: It is fine but you will have to call the async task again and again to check if the data is loaded or not, because calling it once you will just check the above condition once therefore if the data is loaded after calling the async your adapter will not be set.

Comment: I am calling adapter in `onPostExecute`...how about that?

Comment: It is fine when the async is called after the data is loaded, but what when the data is still loading and the async task is already called. your adapter will not set since there is no data.